# Terminal not reporting resize properly

Tags: aix, remote, terminal-emulator, gnome-terminator

I'm having a problem where when I resize my terminal, it doesn't seem to be reported properly and so none of the applications in it don't display properly. For example:

If I open a terminal, remote in to a server and open vim without resizing, vim will take up the entire screen as expected. If I then resize my terminal and open vim again (I'm using vim here as an example but it happens with any program or terminal output), it will still act as if the terminal is the original size.

Is there a way to force my terminal emulator to report this change in size to the remote server?

I'm connecting to AIX machines using Terminator 0.95 on RHEL 6.5, and the shell on the remote server is KSH, for reference.

Thanks!

Edit to answer the questions in the comment below:

`echo $TERM` gives xterm (I'm assuming this is what the default is in terminator, as I haven't changed it). I am logging in using `rsh`

Comment: Can you include in your query the output from `echo $TERM` from your AIX session.  Also, what terminal type have you told Terminator 0.95 to emulate?  Finally, by remote in, do you mean `ssh`, `telnet`, `rlogin`, etc?

Comment: edited my original question to answer these

Comment: Can you use `ssh` and does it work if you do?  I've just installed Terminator v0.95 on Debian and can `ssh` into an AIX machine, TERM is xterm, and it all works fine.

Comment: Using `ssh` appears to solve the issue, yes. The reason I've been using `rsh` instead is because `ssh` can be flaky on these machines, but if that's the problem I will be switching over. Want to post this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested Terminator (on Ubuntu) against an AIX machine using `ssh` and the terminal resize works correctly.

AIX reported `$TERM` as xterm.

It appears either `rsh` is not sending the proper control sequences when Terminator resizes the terminal, or `rshd` is not handling them properly at the AIX end (assumption, untested).

In any case, I recommend using `ssh`!